# Getting an username as ""

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop a login page but when a button is clicked it showing me username as ""

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String userNameValue="abc";
public static final String passwordValue="abc";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditText editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName);
    final String valueUN= editText1.getText().toString();

    EditText editText2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
    final  String valuePW=editText2.getText().toString();

    Button loginButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           if(valueUN==userNameValue && valuePW==passwordValue) {                
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login was Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
        }
    });
}
}
```

when I tried to debug the code using debugger it is displaying valueUN and valuePW as "",why it is showing so? it should display what I enter.

It is not duplicate of question **Get Value of a Edit Text field** cause in that question person wanted to capture value entered in a edittext and mmy question is that edit text is not displaying a right value

Comment: `valueUN==userNameValue` -> [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: yes I should have used ,equals() instead of ==it solved my problem

Comment: Also i should write final String valueUN= editText1.getText().toString(); and final String valuePW= editText2.getText().toString();Inside on click() method

Comment: It's a duplicate because you should look at the answer to that question and do it in the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here

```
EditText editText1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.userName);
final String valueUN= editText1.getText().toString();
```

You are storing value of username in `valueUN` at the same time it is created. You must understand that the time when `edittext` is created, its initial value is `""`. However, when user writes something on it and then performs any action for e.g. click on button in your case, at that time you should get the current value from `edittext`, not at the time it is created.

In your code, try getting value from edittext in `onClickListener()` method.

```
loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override

    public void onClick(View view) {

       String valueUN = editText1.getText().toString();
       String valuePW = editText2.getText().toString();
       if(valueUN.equals(userNameValue) && valuePW.equals(passwordValue)) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Login was Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
       else {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Username or password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
    }
});
```

P.S.: Don't use `==` for String comparison. Instead use `equals()`.

Comment: ,thanks for the explanation on how Editext works it really helped me.